# Can anyone explain why this question was closed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm confused as to why this question was closed. The reason behind the question was programming related and is clearly regarding software commonly used by programmers. Any tips how I could improve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562742/increase-cell-size-limit-in-excel

Comment: It kinda looks like a question regarding the usage of Excel, which is not an acceptable interpretation of "software commonly used by programmers". Maybe add a bit of background, eg. how you create the data you're opening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems pretty clear to me that that's not a programming "problem". That your app is creating a CSV file and you're opening it in Excel and the results aren't what you're expecting has nothing to do with your programming nor will it (probably) have a programming solution.

This problem would certainly be faced by anyone who has a CSV file with large amounts of data in the fields, not just programmers.

It would be very much on-topic at [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Thanks for saving me time, I was about to type the same ;-).

Comment: Well, I guess if he'd added *detailed* info about how he's creating the data, what exactly it looks like, how it's getting cut by Excel (which position?), what character set the file is, etc., it'd have a chance of staying open nevertheless. It's arguably a grey area.

Comment: @Toon: I aim to please.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask there. But I do think if you look through many of the other excel tagged questions you will find many similar things which have not been closed.

Comment: @WebweaverD: And the standard answer there is: That's not evidence for why your question should stay open, but rather that these other questions haven't been noticed yet. By all means bring them to our attention.

Comment: @WebweaverD: Remember too: "Closed" is not an end state. If you can edit the question to make it clearly a programming problem then it can be re-opened.